# Do the new UA Pact of the Tome invocations, Far Scribe and Gift of the Protectors, overlap with one another?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, unearthed-arcana, eldritch-invocations

With the release of the new [UA Class Feature Variants](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/class-feature-variants), do the Eldritch Invocations **Far Scribe** and **Gift of the Protectors** use the same 5 names as a base, or are the names separate for each Invocation?

The [Far Scribe](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf#page=11) eldritch invocation says:

> *Prerequisite: 5th level, Pact of the Tome feature*
>
> A new page appears in your Book of Shadows. With your permission, a creature can use its action to write its name on that page, **which can contain a number of names equal to your Charisma modifier** (minimum of 1).
>
> You can cast the *sending* spell, targeting a creature whose name is on the page, without using a spell slot and without using material components. To do so, you must write the message on the page. The target hears the message in their mind, and if the target replies, their message appears on the page, rather than in your mind. The writing disappears after 1 minute.
>
> As an action, you can magically erase a name on the page by touching the name on it.

The [Gift of the Protectors](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf#page=11) invocation says:

> *Prerequisite: 9th level, Pact of the Tome feature*
>
> A new page appears in your Book of Shadows. With your permission, a creature can use its action to write its name on that page, **which can contain a number of names equal to your Charisma modifier** (minimum of 1).
>
> When any creature whose name is on the page is reduced to 0 hit points but not killed outright, the creature magically drops to 1 hit point instead. Once this magic is triggered, no creature can benefit from it until you finish a long rest.
>
> As an action, you can magically erase a name on the page by touching the name on it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### They are separate lists

This is shown as the features both start with the following:

> **A new page appears** in your Book of Shadows [...]

This means that both features must exist on *different* pages and the features then go on to clarify that they only apply to names on that specific page:

> [...] targeting a creature whose name is on **the page** [...]
>
> [...] When any creature whose name is on **the page** [...]

Thus, because the features use different pages, and each feature can only use a name from its own page, they are completely separate in who they can affect.